# Renaming/replacing primary key to query across schemas

Tags: datajoint

I currently have two separate schemas for processed calcium imaging data, in which I've used two different preprocessing methods. The big goal of what I am trying to do is use sources from 1 schema as a reference and pull out the corresponding sources in the second schema. I have done source matching so that I know for each neuron in schema1 what its corresponding neuron in schema2 is.

In a table in schema1, each neuron has an integer primary key called `neurID` and a foreign key (`schema2ID`) with the corresponding primary key for that neuron in schema2. The problem I am running into is that in schema2, each neuron's primary key is *also* called `neurID`, so this is not the same neuron as in schema1 (e.g., a neuron in schema1 with `neurID` = 1, `schema2ID` = 15 would correspond to a neuron in schema2 with `neurID` = 15, `schema1ID` = 1).

Ideally, what I would want to do is once I have all the neurons from 1 schema for which I have their corresponding IDs in schema2, I would replace their primary key `neurID` with the foreign key `schema2ID` so that I could now use that to get the corresponding neurons in schema2 (since the `schema2ID` in schema1 is the same as the `neurID` schema2 primary key). Is there any way to rename a primary key in this way? Or is there some other hacky approach that I could use through creating new tables?

(Note that this is all further complicated by the fact that I also have another primary key 'targID' in each schema for which the indexing also does not mean the same thing across schemas.)

I would really appreciate any tips, as I'm quite stuck. Also happy to show code more directly through DMs etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps using DataJoint's projection operator (`.proj()`) would help in your case. The `.proj()` operation can be used to rename attributes, see https://docs.datajoint.io/python/queries/08-Proj.html?highlight=project

Take your above example, you can try this:

```
schema1_table * schema2_table.proj(schema2ID='neurID')
```

or the opposite would work too:

```
schema1_table.proj(schema1ID='neurID') * schema2_table
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me. When getting the final neurons that I want and trying to project out the foreign key to the primary key name, I end up with an invalid variable (```1x1 dj.internal.GeneralRelvar```). This might be because what I'm trying to do is more complicated than starting with a single table (i.e., many within-schema joins before getting to the final neurons that I want to grab in the other schema)?